ansible config not using inventory file specified in ansible.cfg
I have an ansible.cfg file in my root directory where I am running my playbooks. If I trying and listing the inventory by just running ansible-inventory --list I do not see the host that are listed in the inventory. Seems like ansible is not wanting to use the inventory file listed in the ansible.cfg. In my ansible.cfg in the local directory I have inventory = /home/root/ansible/inventory. I have ran a -vv for ansible-inventory list and I get the below output. look like it is using the /etc/ansible/hosts file instead of the one specified in the inventory. Any idea why this is not using the inventory file specified in the local ansible.cfg.
ansible-inventory [core 2.15.6]
  config file = /home/root/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-inventory
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
Using /home/root/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}


Ansible config file
[inventory]
enable_plugins = yaml, ini
inventory = /home/root/ansible/inventory

[default]
host_key_checking = false
remote_user = ansible
#gather_facts = no

[privilege_escalation]
become = true


if I point directly to the inventory file using -i the host are parsed correctly. So the inventory file is fine. I also tried running a command to see if other settings in the ansible.cfg were picked up and it does not seem to pick those up either. I tried doing a ping using ansible -i inventory -m ping host1 thinking it should have used the remote user listed in the config and it tried connecting with the root user I was logged in with.

I just updated my ansible.cfg file in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg with the settings I have posted earlier in my cfg in the current directory. Even with that being update ansible is not using what is set in the config. What do I need to check to see why it is not using that config when I run a playbook? If I view with ansible-config it shows the right information.
